# Clustering microblogs

Tags: clustering

I have a microblog dataset with about 100k tweets and I would like to cluster them effectively using some less advanced algorithm. Is there anywhere I can find like a single-pass K-Means or similar algorithms. Thanks.

I have tried using K-Means and it takes about 5 minutes to cluster 100k tweets, using standard pre-processing (tokenization, stemming). I have also used Online LDA, but I can't retrieve tweets from the topics.

Answer (score 2):

With single-pass algorithms you won't be able to discover useful structure. K-means already is too simple for actual structure discovery; it's merely a vector quantization method.

100k isn't a lot, it should run in a few minutes with full k-means, actually...

Have you experimented with hashing, in particularly LSH/MinHash? These seem to be fairly standard techniques. Please update your question and list what you have already tried.